# MSAccess query to search against a list of criteria in a data table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to build some discount list for products. I have a main table that contains conditions:

```
ID  Connection  Class           Discount
1   (B OR F)    150             0.1
2   B           (600 OR 900)    0.2
3   F           (1500 OR 2500)  0.3
4   (C OR F)    4500            0.25
```

Query I am trying to do is something like this:

```
SELECT Constraints.Discount
FROM Constraints
WHERE ((('600')=[Class]));
```

The example above should return row 2. How can this be done? Do I need to format my conditions in a different way? I have tried this example and could not get the result I want. The idea is to build multiple columns of constraints and depending on what configuration is selected I would like to narrow down to the correct discount applicable.

Please let me know if there is an easier way to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Your data isn't normalised. Each distinct possible value should be a separate record. Then this query becomes simple.

Comment: You could split the Connection and Class data into two columns each.

Comment: All columns are split. I apologize for not indenting properly in this example.

Comment: Possible connections can only be: B, C or F. Possible Classes can only be 150, 600, 900, 1500, 2500, 4500

Comment: This table would be used to create constraint rules such as (150 OR 300 OR 600 OR 900) under the class column

Comment: Hi, I have still not received a viable solution to this problem. I am trying to create a rule table that I need to query from in order to match a pattern. So far the solutions I've gotten are traditional queries.

Answer (score 1):

As @Minty said in a comment - your data isn't normalised.  If you were to split `Connection` and `Class` so they only contained a single value you could easily pull the data back.

```
| ID | Connection | Class | Discount |
|----|------------|-------|----------|
| 1  | B          | 150   | 0.1      |
| 1  | F          | 150   | 0.1      |
| 2  | B          | 600   | 0.2      |
| 2  | B          | 900   | 0.2      |
| 3  | F          | 1500  | 0.3      |
| 3  | F          | 2500  | 0.3      |
| 4  | C          | 4500  | 0.25     |
| 4  | F          | 4500  | 0.25     |
```

This SQL would return 0.2:

```
SELECT  Discount
FROM    Constraints
WHERE   Class = 600
```

I expect you'd have to bring in `Connection` as the class on its own would bring back duplicate records (unless you group by `Discount` based on the sample data).

So either:

```
SELECT  Discount
FROM    Table2
WHERE   Connection = 'B' AND Class = 600
```

Or

```
SELECT  Discount
FROM    Table2
WHERE   Class = 150
GROUP BY Discount
```

Edit:  `< ID, Connection, Class >` can make up the composite `Primary Key` in the table.

Comment: Hi, the point of this exercise is not to end up with millions of combinations. I need to create a table that contains constraints. This way I can describe a discount on one single line with constraints for every field. Instead of millions of rows I end up with a small list of 20 rules for example. Does that make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but I don't think that will be using the power of the database.  With the correct indexes set up the query should search the millions of normalised rows faster than it can search a few thousand non-normalised rows.

Comment: The problem is in this example I have only connection and class. Normalizing for 20 more fields like this might bring the number of rows to billions or trillions now that I look at all the combinations. I cannot have a database that huge.

Comment: I'd still write the code to normalise it so I could test for speed, and if it was too slow I'd think of another way - someway of reducing the combinations through table relationships.

Comment: I've used pattern matching such as this: [FR]08-[01237]0[67]4E-* in one column and was able to match it against a criteria such as 'F10-1064C-02TY' This works, however I wish to do this on multiple columns instead and with multiple characters. I think I am starting to realize that what I am trying to achieve is a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

What data type is the Class column.  If it is a number try the following query:

```
SELECT Constraints.Discount
FROM Constraints
WHERE [Class] = 600
```

`'600'` is a string constant that contains the 3 characters `6`, `0`, and `0` -- this is different than a numeric value of 600

Comment: yes assume that it is a string. I want it to be applicable to mostly strings anyways. So maybe I should have put in my example '600' OR '900'